# Script to find duplicate files by extension and delete them

Tags: shell-script, find, deduplication

Recently my NAS was ransomware attacked and all my files were `7z`ipped. I managed to get the password and extract them and at the same time I renamed the *7zipped* file to `7z.bad` (so that it's easier later to delete just the affected files and not any actual `.7z` files I already had before the attack).

This is the script I used to extract and rename the files:

```bsh
while [ -n "$(find . -type f -name '*.7z' -print -quit)" ]
do 
    find . -type f -name "*.7z" -execdir /usr/local/sbin/7z x -pPASSWORD {} \; -execdir mv {} {}".bad" \;
done
```

So, what I have now is a lot of duplicates, like this:

```
Phone book.xlsx
Phone book.xlsx.7z.bad
```

What I would like to do is:

1. Look for any `.7z.bad` files in the current directory (and all subdirectories)
2. For any `.7z.bad` file found, **if** the same file without .7z.bad extension is also present:
3. Delete the `.7z.bad` file

The reason I want to check for the original file's presence is just for another level of security.

I am afraid I won't be able to install any other tools (like `fdupes`) in my Qnap NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for name do rm -f -- "$name.7z.bad"; done' sh {} +
```

The above finds *all* regular files in or below the current directory, and then tries to delete all of them, but adds `.7z.bad` to the end of the names first.

This way, all files with names ending in `.7z.bad` are deleted if there are corresponding files without that filename suffix.

Testing in an otherwise empty directory:

```
$ touch file-{1..5}.txt.7z.bad
$ touch file-{1..3}.txt
$ ls
file-1.txt        file-2.txt        file-3.txt        file-4.txt.7z.bad
file-1.txt.7z.bad file-2.txt.7z.bad file-3.txt.7z.bad file-5.txt.7z.bad
```

```
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for name do rm -f -- "$name.7z.bad"; done' sh {} +
```

```
$ ls
file-1.txt        file-2.txt        file-3.txt        file-4.txt.7z.bad file-5.txt.7z.bad
```

Comment: what is the need for bringing in the shell when all you're doing is removing the files? -exec rm -f {} + would delete just as well

Comment: @guest_7 I'm not actually deleting the pathnames that `find` gives me, I add a filename suffix to each name first.  Otherwise I would remove _all_ files!

Comment: Iam not sure to follow this? It will also delete  file that has double.7z.bad extension? But otherwise a good approach!

Comment: @guest_7 It will certainly _try_ to delete files that have `.7z.bad.7z.bad` filename suffixes.  That's ok though as they don't exist and I'm running with `rm -f` (which means the deletion of non-existent files won't be generating any errors).

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*.7z.bad" -exec sh -c '
  for file; do
    if [ -f "${file%.7z.bad}" ]; then
      rm -- "$file"
    else
      echo "keeping file $file" >&2
    fi
  done
' sh {} +
```

This passes all filenames found by `find` to the shell script which then loops over the filenames and checks if each filename without the `.7z.bad` suffix
exists. If this is the case, it deletes the file with the `.7z.bad` suffix or prints a warning message otherwise.

Replace `-f` with `-s` if you want to test if the unzipped file exists *and* has a non-zero file size.